# Driver problem and back-office access prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Accuse of problem of access to the back-office in prestashop1.7
I see the message below
Can you direct me to find a lead?

Another point I noticed that the App/config/config.yml file contains an error on line 28? What can I do to solve my problem?

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K_e1r1WPnIk6djLZZyFPaOGz5sw21tApZjidxwf67TM/edit?usp=sharing
```

I'm waiting for my problem to be solved because I can't connect to my back office

Thanks

Comment: Fixed issue you need to reinstall the PHP version on your server and the back office will work